# EXCEL increase the cell row referenced by 11

Tags: excel, function, formula

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7xsNQ.png)I'm needing a formula that will increase the cell row reference by 11 when i copy it down along a column (hoping that makes sense).

Currently the formula runs:

```
=INDIRECT("'"&$A$1&"'!$D10")
=INDIRECT("'"&$A$1&"'!$D21")
=INDIRECT("'"&$A$1&"'!$D32")
=INDIRECT("'"&$A$1&"'!$D43")
```

etc.

That continues for another all the way to D340, and I need to duplicate the table another 8 times with different column references, so i'd really appreciate a quicker solution!

I've had a mess around with functions like OFFSET, but as yet to no avail. Wondering if anyone knows the function and formula that will increase the row reference by 11 automatically when I use 'fill'.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
 =(ROW(A1)-1)*11 + 10
```

Like this:

```
=INDIRECT("'"&$A$1&"'!$D"&(ROW(A1)-1)*11 + 10)
```

Comment: You sir are a life saver! Much appreciated

Comment: No problem @danny, if this answered your question - please accept the answer by clicking the tick mark.

Comment: Ah one hitch, It works fine for the D and E references but not for J K P Q V & W. what do I need to edit?

Comment: What is the error? You might need to put up some screenshots so I can help you further

Comment: So 
    =INDIRECT("'"&$A$1&"'!$D"&(ROW(A1)-1)*11 + 10)
    =INDIRECT("'"&$A$1&"'!$E"&(ROW(B1)-1)*11 + 10)
Have worked successfully. 

But when I go the next table (on the same sheet) and use the formula 

    =INDIRECT("'"&$A$1&"'!$J"&(ROW(A1)-1)*11 + 10)

It doest return the correct information from the table, which should be number of hours a worked and holiday hours used

Comment: What is in $A$1? Does it return errors or just incorrect/no data? It might be easiest if you take a few screenshots and add them to your original question

Comment: So the first two (which have worked), are displaying the information from a different sheet, in this case, 'Period 1' (thats what the indirect function is being used for) cells D10 and E10, respectively. However when I use the formula a few columns over to reference 'Period 1' J10 and K10 it's not displaying the information contained in those cells

Comment: Select the cell which isn't evaluating to J10 and go to the ribbon and click Formulas>Evaluate Formula and keep clicking Evaluate.. just before it finishes you should see =Period1!J10. If not what do you see?

Comment: Fixed it! Just needed to change the the ROW( to A1. Thank for all help!